# WCF, Xamarin - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

Trying to make a WCF Webservice for my xamarin forms app. It should just retreive text from sqlserver and fill a label with it.
The wcf method return a `List` of `OfflineContent` objects, as there may be more than one result for the sql request.
But when I try to call the method from client, I have this:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I think i missed something but can't figured out what.

Here is project structure and code.

[image: solution structure]

IBienEtreService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBienEtreService
{
   [OperationContract]
   List<OfflineContent> GetDataContent(string title);
}

[DataContract]
public class OfflineContent
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Title { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Text { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Picture { get; set; }
}
```

BienEtreService.svc

```
public List<OfflineContent> GetDataContent(string title)
{
   List<OfflineContent> ContentList = new List<OfflineContent>();
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Content where title = @title", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      OfflineContent content = new OfflineContent
      {
         Title = reader.GetString(1),
         Text = reader.GetString(2)
      };
      ContentList.Add(content);
    }
    return ContentList;
}
```

At this point ContentList contain what I need.

The issue comes here in Lef_methode.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Left_Methode : ContentPage
{
    static BienEtreServiceClient client1 = new BienEtreServiceClient();
    public Left_Methode ()
    {
       InitializeComponent ();
       //This fails
       List<Content> list = client1.GetDataContentAsync("methode");
       Mthd_txt.Text = "It's the label, should contain something like list[1].texte";
    }
}
```

I seen the return type of GetDataContentAsync (I have to use the Async? I can't call the method directly without suffixes) is void in Reference.cs, which is generated automatically... And i need a `List<OfflineContent>` return type.

Can someone show me the right way please? The struggle is real i come back to dev after a long break.

Comment: don't you mean to call `GetDataContent`?

Comment: Yes i want to simply call this method, but can't: http://hpics.li/e4cc423

Comment: I think the `GetDataContentAsync` method is generated automatically. You should assign the event `GetDataContentAsync_Response` to handle the return or use it on a async method and `await` the result before try to get it. You will not able to do it at constructor

Comment: When you generated the client did you choose Task based methods or the callback type?

Comment: @Crowcoder i don't have choice but callback type : http://hpics.li/a3dea38

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza do you have a working sample? I tried this but doesn't work either http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.fr/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-in-wcf.html

Comment: Then you have to use a callback to access the result or use a synchronous version if there is one.

Comment: I haven't. But the link you share do have. Just the first code sample. I was wrong abou the method name. It's not `GetDataContentAsync_Response`, it's `GetDataContentCompleted`. Try this way.

Comment: Trying the 1st code of the link, but the GetDataContentAsync is still returning void and i don't get where is stored the list from GetDataContent. In the GetDataContentCompletedEventArgs e?